# jQuery select2 - change the selected values when a certain value is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin for doing a ajax-based multi-select.

What I want to do is when a user selects an item from a drop down and if that item is of a certain value, I want to change the list of selected items.

So,

```
vals = $(".myselect").select("val")
if _.indexOf(vals, "particular_value") > -1
  $(".myselect").select("val", ["another value"])
```

However, it doesn't actually update the selected values visually. But if I do

```
vals = $(".myselect").select("val")
if _.indexOf(vals, "particular_value") > -1
  $(".myselect").select("val", ["another value"])
  console.log $(".myselect").select("val")
```

Then I get ["another value"] on the console, which is correct. It's not juist being reflected on the actual element.

I also tried

```
  $(".myselect").select("val", ["another value"]).trigger("change")
```

But still not being updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this:

```
$(".select").select2("val","SomeValue");
```

[**HERE**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) is the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation)